# ReSharper not supporting Assert.That

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resharper, assert

I'm in the process of returning to ReSharper recently, using trial of the newest version - 2022.2.3. I've got quite surprised when one of my nUnit tests failed in a weird way, when run by Resharper's built in Unit Test runner. Something that has never happened to me with a Test Explorer.

As long as the Asserts pass, it's all fine - green, all tests are listed. However, when the assert fails, it says `One or more child tests had errors. Exception doesn't have a stacktrace`

Not only there is no mention of actual values that weren't correct, but the whole failing test seems to be gone!
This happens only when I use the 'modern' approach with `Assert.That`. So

```
Assert.That(httpContext.Response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(200));
```

is causing issues, meanwhile, the more classic:

```
Assert.AreEqual(200, httpContext.Response.StatusCode);
```

works as expected. Is that something that is a known bug, or maybe some attributes are required? JetBrains claims they have full support of nUnit out of the box, so that is a bit surprising.

NOTE: the tests methods are async, awaiting result and returning Tasks, beside this nothing unusual.
[image: Resharper vs VS]
[image: Also resharper, but with passing tests]

EDIT: The test code is as follows, ApiKeyMiddleware is any middleware that returns response with 200 here.

```
[TestFixture]
public class ApiKeyMiddlewareTests
{
    [Test]
    public async Task Invoke_ActiveKey_Authorized()
    {
        var httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext();
        httpContext.Request.Headers.Add("XXXXX", "xxxx");

        var configuration = Options.Create(new AccessConfiguration { ActiveApiKeys = new List<string> { "xxxx" } });

        var middleware = new ApiKeyMiddleware(GetEmptyRequest(), configuration);

        await middleware.Invoke(httpContext);
        Assert.That(httpContext.Response.StatusCode, Is.EqualTo(200));  //change to anything else than 200 and it fails + vanishes
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show more of your test code, please? Because I wasn't able to reproduce

Comment: sure, just added an update with the code

Comment: Without `ApiKeyMiddleware`, it is still impossible to help you  please always provide a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: For some reason I cannot reproduce it again, I guess it had to be a remporary bug, maybe some caching issue.